# Why does an Excel Table function with IF filter with AND condition not return results

Tags: excel, if-statement, pivot-table, percentile

I have an Excel book here where I have imported data from CSV, aggregated in a Pivot table. I need to calculate Percentiles on the aggregation, and the function

```
{=PERCENTILE.INC(IF(MyTable[label]=$A3,MyTable[elapsed]),$C$1)}
```

did return a result.(`$A3` is the pivot table row label, $C$1` contains 0.9, = 90%)
I tried to extend the filtering IF statement with another condition using AND but suddenly the Percentile output dropped to 0.
For debug reasons I simplified my condition down to the following:

```
{=PERCENTILE.INC(IF(AND(MyTable[label]=$A3, TRUE()),MyTable[elapsed]),$C$1)}
```

The expectation was that the formula result should be identical to the one above but with that AND statement it returns 0. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AND` only returns a single value (`TRUE` if all conditions are fulfilled, `FALSE` otherwise), it can't return an array, which is what you need here - you can either multiply the conditions with * which mimics `AND` but does return an array, e.g.

`=PERCENTILE.INC(IF((MyTable[label]=$A3)*(Another_condition=TRUE),MyTable[elapsed]),$C$1)`

or use another IF like this:

`=PERCENTILE.INC(IF(MyTable[label]=$A3,IF(Another_condition=TRUE,MyTable[elapsed])),$C$1)`